# How to calculate the initial Stock with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the initial stock by the number of weeks.
I'm have just managed to calculate the 'in' and 'out' of stock between the weeks 10 and 20   with this request.

Can someone give me the  full request to calculate the final stock and the initial stock.

```
SELECT 
      `week` ,
       SUM(case
         when  `week` between 10 AND 20 and `etat` =1
         then 1
         else 0
       end) AS inn
       ,
       SUM(case
         when `week` between 10 AND 20   and `etat` =2
         then 1
         else 0
       end)  AS out

       FROM fait_stock f
       where 1=1
       group by `week` 
       having `week` between 10 AND 20
```

**EDIT**

I want to calculate the stock of the previous weeks (initial stock that means weeks<10) for example week 10 I have 5. week 11 It should be 5+(stock of week 11). Week 12 it should be 5+(stock of week 11)+(stock of week 12) the same for others weeks.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `1=1`?

Comment: Nothing you can delete it

Comment: What is the need of this `having week between 10 AND 20` ?

Comment: Also, provide a little set of data example and what would be the desired result from it.

Comment: I want to calculate the stock of the previous weeks (initial stock that s mean weeks<10)  for example week 10 I have 5.  week 11 It should be 5+(stock of week 11).  Week 12 it should be 5+(stock of week 11)+(stock of week 12) the same for others weeks..  And sorry for my english.. Thank youu

Comment: @MohamedAmine, In future, please edit your post with clarifications. Note how I have done it for you; it is clear what you have added.  You really need to provide tabulated sample data for a number of weeks and the  the figures you want to arrive at.  It doesn't require explanation, just the figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - you can write your query much shorter:

```sql
SELECT 
    `week` ,
    SUM(IF(`etat`=1, 1, 0)) AS inn,
    SUM(IF(`etat`=2, 1, 0)) AS `out`
FROM fait_stock
WHERE `week` BETWEEN 10 AND 20
GROUP BY `week`
```

If you now join it with itself (with a small modification, if you want the sums of weeks < 10), you can calculate the sums for all weeks that are smaller or equal than the given week:

```sql
SELECT f1.`week`, SUM(f2.inn) AS inn, SUM(f2.`out`) AS `out`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        `week` ,
        SUM(IF(`etat`=1, 1, 0)) AS inn,
        SUM(IF(`etat`=2, 1, 0)) AS `out`
    FROM fait_stock
    WHERE `week` BETWEEN 10 AND 20
    GROUP BY `week`
) AS f1
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        `week` ,
        SUM(IF(`etat`=1, 1, 0)) AS inn,
        SUM(IF(`etat`=2, 1, 0)) AS `out`
    FROM fait_stock
    WHERE `week` BETWEEN 1 AND 20
    GROUP BY `week`
) AS f2 ON f2.`week` <= f1.`week`
GROUP BY f1.`week`
```